# Can't figure out what's triggering "java.util.ConcurrentModificationException"

Tags: java, exception

My code is throwing an error that I've never seen before. So hey! I guess I'm learning ;) Anyway, I did some reading and generally this error is thrown when a list that is being iterated over is modified mid-iteration. However, I'm pretty sure I'm not modifying it. While the error is being thrown on partition(), if I don't assign a new value for currentList in updateCurrentList() (by commenting out the code), the program no longer throws the error. These two functions are called one after the other in my play() method, however the list iteration should be complete by the time the change is made. What am I missing? Do I have to close down the iterator somehow?

```
package hangman;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Hangman {
    private Map<String, List<String>> wordPartitions; // groups words according to positions of guessed letter
    private List<String> currentList; // remaining possible words that fit the information given so far
    Set<Character> wrongGuesses; // holds all the "wrong" guesses so far
    StringBuilder guessString; // current state of the word being guessed
    String justHyphens; // for checking whether a guess was "wrong"

    // initialize fields
    // currentList should contain all (and only) words of length wordLength

// justHyphens and guessString should consist of wordLength hyphens
public Hangman(int wordLength) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this.currentList = new ArrayList<String>();
    addWords(wordLength);
    wrongGuesses = new HashSet();

    for(int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
        justHyphens += "-";
    }
    guessString = new StringBuilder();
    wordPartitions = new HashMap();
}

private void addWords(int wordLength) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner words = new Scanner(new File("lexicon.txt"));
    String word = "";

    while(words.hasNext()) {
        word = words.next();
        if (word.length() == wordLength) {
            currentList.add(word);
        }
    }
}

// main loop
public void play() {
    char choice;

    do {
        choice = getUserChoice();
        partition(choice);
        updateCurrentList(choice);
    } while (!gameOver());
        endMessage();
}

// display the guessString and the missed guesses
// and get the next guess
private char getUserChoice() {
   //generate a string from the incorrect choices char list
    String wrong = "";
    char letter;

    if(!wrongGuesses.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator<Character> letters = wrongGuesses.iterator();
        letter = letters.next(); 

        while(letters.hasNext()) {
            letter = letters.next();
            wrong += ", " + letter;
        }
    }

    String letterStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Incorrect choices: "+ wrong +"\n Tested letters: "+ guessString.toString() +"\nplease input a letter.");
    return letterStr.charAt(0);
}


// use wordPartitions to partition currentList using
// keys returned by getPartitionKey()
private void partition(char choice) {

    String word = "";
    String key = "";
    List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();

    Iterator<String> words = currentList.iterator();
    //Generate a key for each word and add to appropriate arraylist within map.
    while(words.hasNext()) {
        word = words.next();
        key = getPartitionKey(word, choice);

        if(wordPartitions.containsKey(key)) {
            tempList = wordPartitions.get(key);
            tempList.add(word);
            wordPartitions.put(key, tempList);
        } else {
            tempList.clear();
            tempList.add(word);
            wordPartitions.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());                
        }            
    }
}

// update currentList to be a copy of the longest partition
// if choice was "wrong", add choice to wrongGuesses
// if choice was "right", update guessString
private void updateCurrentList(char choice) {        
    String key = findLongestList();

    currentList = wordPartitions.get(key);

    if(key.equals(justHyphens)) {
        wrongGuesses.add(choice);
    } else {
        addLetterToGuessString(guessString, choice, key);
    }
}

private String findLongestList() {
    Set<String> keySet = wordPartitions.keySet();
    Iterator<String> keys = keySet.iterator();
    String maxKey = "";
    int maxKeyLength = 0;
    List<String> tempList;
    String tempKey = "";

    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        tempKey = keys.next();
        tempList = wordPartitions.get(tempKey);

        if(tempList.size() > maxKeyLength) {
            maxKeyLength = tempList.size();
            maxKey = tempKey;
        }
    }

    return maxKey;
}

// checks for end of game
private boolean gameOver() {
    return false;
}

// display the guessString and the missed guesses
// and print "Congratulations!"
private void endMessage() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congrats, yo!");
}

// returns string with '-' in place of each
// letter that is NOT the guessed letter
private String getPartitionKey(String s, char c) {
    String word = "";
    String letter = Character.toString(c);
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i) == c) {
            word += letter;
        } else {
            word += "-";
        }
    }

    return word;
}
// update guessString with the guessed letter
private void addLetterToGuessString(StringBuilder guessString, char letter, String key) {
    for(int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
        if(key.charAt(i) != '-') {
            guessString.setCharAt(i, key.charAt(i)); 
        } 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: where is this play() method that you have mentioned?

Comment: Provide code that run or fire those methods.

Comment: Thanks! Added that code at the top of the code sample.

Comment: I'd also be happy to provide my entire class, I just wasn't sure if that was the right thing to do. Please let me know if that would be better.

Comment: And the stack trace of the exception is?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
 at hangman.Hangman.partition(Hangman.java:93)
 at hangman.Hangman.play(Hangman.java:54)
 at hangman.TestClient.main(TestClient.java:14)

Comment: And TestClient.main is just creating a new Hangman object and calling the play() method.

Comment: You're modifying a collection that you're ierating over. It's hard to explain where, because we don't have the complete code.

Comment: @JBNizet I went ahead and edited the post to include the entire code sample. Thanks so much for taking a look :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are modifying a collection while you are iterating over it.

The collection is `currentList`, you are iterating over it in `partition()`. You modify it when you add a word to `tempList` here:

```
key = getPartitionKey(word, choice);

if(wordPartitions.containsKey(key)) {
    tempList = wordPartitions.get(key);
    tempList.add(word);
    wordPartitions.put(key, tempList);
} else {
```

Why ? Because previously you called `updateCurrentList()` from `play()`:

```
do {
    choice = getUserChoice();
    partition(choice);
    updateCurrentList(choice);
} while (!gameOver());
```

And you updated `currentList`:

```
String key = findLongestList();

currentList = wordPartitions.get(key);
```

So, if the `key` returned by `getPartitionKey(word, choice)` is the same as the key previously returned by `findLongestList()`, `currentList`will be the same as `tempList`, and so you will be modifying the collection you are iterating over.

The solution ? If `tempList` is the same as `currentList`, don't add the word to it (it already have the word, by definition). So, you can rewrite your if-else like that (I removed some useless code):

```
if(wordPartitions.containsKey(key)) {
    tempList = wordPartitions.get(key);
} else {
    wordPartitions.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());                
}

if (tempList!=currentList) {
    tempList.add(word);
}
```